# htaccess RewriteCond and RedirectMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http

I have enabled RewriteEngine within my .htaccess file. I have a condition to remove the "www" from any request. This works just fine. However I am also using RedirectMatch to do a 301 redirect. This works as well except that the request URI from the original incoming url is appended to the end of the url which I am 301 redirecting to.

Input URL:

```
http://www.example.com/newplate
```

Output URL:

```
http://example.com/contact/motorv.php?/newplate
```

Existing .htaccess file

```
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml .html .htm .php


RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]


#straight 301 redirects
RedirectMatch 301 ^/newplate(.*) /contact/motorv.php


#if request is not an existing file or directory then redirect to
#codeigniter boot.php file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ boot.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

How should this issue be resolved? Is there something I have overlooked or written incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#straight 301 redirects
RewriteRule ^newplate(.*) /contact/motorv.php [NC,L,R=301]
```